# Easiest way to create offset animation on a number of objects

Tags: animation

I’m wondering what’s the easiest approach to creating offset animation on a number of objects. By that I mean having a range of objects where each object follows the rotation of the first object with an offset of a few frames per copy, preferably linked to the original animation, so changing the animation for all objects is easy.

If an add-on like [Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases) or [Animax](https://blendermarket.com/products/animax---procedural-animation-system-?ref=2) is the best way to go, I’ll install that, but I’d prefer to do it without add-ons.

Thanks.

Comment: You could do it with NLA or using the Offset value of the Follow Path constraint, but, it depends on what you mean by "each object follows the rotation of the first object", it's a bit vague, perhaps show a drawing?

Comment: You can try to create the parent child chain. Uncheck **inherit location** to only inherit rotation, and then use the parent offset. (untested, not on a computer right now)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, appreciated.

@moonboots: I mean a row of objects, where the rotation of the first one is replicated in the other ones, but with a delay.

Leander: Do you mean the Slow Parent option that was present in Blender prior to 2.8? I've been solely using 2.8 for the project thus far.

Comment: do you know how the NLA works? If not, it might help you, if you do know, why don't you have what you want with NLA?

Comment: @moonboots: Never worked with NLA in Blender to date. I know what it is, and will check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is the addon [Animation Replicator with Offset](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-animation-replicator-with-offset-arewo/599020) that seems to do what you want.

I have used it before with success to create a series of objects that slowly rotate one by one in sequence.

While still relying on an add-on to create the objects, it is a tool type of addon, with a "use it once and discard" sort of workflow.

It doesn't need to be permanently installed for the animations to keep working, it just creates regular Blender animations using native features.

Once it has done its work, you can uninstall it, and things will keep working properly, afterwards, so you can freely share or reopen the file without losing your work.

Comment: Thanks Duarte! I'm afraid that Arewo has become dated and won't work in Blender 2.8, but I guess I'll go for Animation Nodes or Animax, both of which can do similar things.